# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am having issues with my tableView not firing the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. I have implemented the delegates as such:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

And in my storyboard the tableView's data source and delegate are both pointed at the base View Controller. I have User Interactions enabled as well as Selection set to Single Selection, and it is not the TapGesture problem since my tap gestures are not bound to the view and I have checked and they do not fire.

This is the code for setting up the table:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return menuArray.count;
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"menuCell"];
    NSDictionary *menuItem = [menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = menuItem[@"Title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = menuItem[@"Subtitle"];
    return cell;
}
-(void)showMenu{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
        [content setFrame:CGRectMake(menuTable.frame.size.width, content.frame.origin.y, content.frame.size.width, content.frame.size.height)];
    }];
}
-(void)hideMenu{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
    [content setFrame:CGRectMake(0, content.frame.origin.y, content.frame.size.width,     content.frame.size.height)];
    }];
}
-(IBAction)showMenuDown:(id)sender {
    if(content.frame.origin.x == 0)
        [self showMenu];
    else
        [self hideMenu];
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //whatever
}
```

The table is initially out of view on the storyboard (origin.x is set to -150), then when the user clicks on a button in the navigationBar, the view slides over to reveal it, which is what might be causing the problem I think.

Is there anything wrong with my code or implementation that would be causing this to not work?

Comment: Probably an obvious question, but are you sure that you've set both the delegate and the dataSource of the tableView?

Comment: @cobbal yeah i connected them in the storyboard to the view controller and i implemented them in the .h file

Comment: add `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. If the row is deselected when you lift your finger, the problem is in your `changeImage:` method.

Comment: @Jsdodgers dude it doesn't even enter didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: There's no clue (or hope for a clue) in the code you posted.  Does the tableView have selection enabled?  That setting is under TableView in IB, where there's a "Selection" drop down.

Comment: Views, tableviews and cells all have userInteractionEnabled property.  Have you checked all three?

Comment: @gta0004 Did you try it though to confirm?

Comment: @Jsdodgers yeah i put NSLog's everywhere to make sure it didn't go into the function and that it wasn't firing tap gesture events either

Comment: @danh dude they are all checked

Comment: Are you sure you typed `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and not `didDeselectRowATIndexPath`?

Comment: @Jsdodgers i pasted that code straight from my project

Comment: @gta0004, what is `–changeImage:` method? what does it want to change? how it works? please, post the method, nobody can read in your mind and figured out what exactly not working in a method what you haven't shared with us...

Comment: @holex thats not relevant if it never gets called dude

Comment: @gta0004, dude, then what is your problem? because what you've shared is fine. you did something wrong somewhere else... what does the `userInteractionEnabled` value say? what does the `allowsSelection` value say? have you checked them?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Tap Gestures you mention and seeing if the problem persists? I'm sure userInteraction isn't the issue since scrolling probably works or you'd have a different question.

Answer (score 0):

If you already see your table populated with values from your dictionary then you can rule out  data source and delegate as being the problem. i.e. your storyboard connections are working.

Your code looks fine to me. the only difference I see is I usually define my table like this. Try this and see if it helps.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //NSLog(@"Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier.
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        // Use the default cell style.
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

//Your code here
// ....

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"menuCell"];
```

This will return nil in case there was never a cell created.

so checking if cell is nil is mandatory and if so, you need to create a cell.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"menuCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

---

as you are using storyboard you can alternatively use

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

for prototype cells. Make sure you use the same identifier in the storyboard and that you registered your the cell's class

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"menuCell"];
}
```